# doctype related error is shown during importing mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I have a database in godaddy server. It is around 10 Mb . I exported it successfully then I want to import the database in another server(say my local server). But when I import it following error is displayed.

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w' at line 1`

I have never seen this kind of problem before . I tried to google the answer but could not find any help. How do I solve this error.

**I checked for all tables if it contained "Doctype" word anywhere using "LIKE" statement**

[image: Error message being displayed]

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your exported database file gets corrupted because a bad connection with your host during the export.

When everything works fine, you should have an exported databse file that ends with something like "/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;"

In my case I had

```
</body>
</html>
```

so that makes it an html file instead of a SQL file and creates the error on the import.
So try to export your database on a different way. In my case I tried a day later and the connection was better and it worked out fine.